# SimpleHTMLDOM use in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, parsing, customization

My problem is, I'm looking to use the [Php Simple Html Dom Parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) but, the file appears to be just a set of `functions` and not a `class SomeClass{}` declaration therefore, making it difficult to embed as a *custom* `library` in codeigniter like after I've declared it.
$this->load->library('someclass');

I've put this code in pastebin for Simple Html Dom Parser:
http://pastebin.com/0rR6Kiex

I'm wondering how can I easily make all those functions availiable via a class I define like:

```
class MyClass{
   ## contents of pastebin here

}
```

so I can load in codeigniter, like:

```
$this->load->library('myclass');
$thus->myclass->fetchlinks();
```

Currently, I'm trying to manually require a php file, which kinda defeats the point of using codeigniter:

```
function fetchlinks(){
    ## include the Simpledom framework #########################################################
    include "localhost/mysite/assets/php/Simpledom.php" or die('Error occured on page');   #
}
```

Comment: http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/creating_libraries.html

Comment: Thanks for the link, I currently already have seen that. Its not a problem with CI as much as a problem with the library "Simple Dom Parser" setup. (You will see that in the pastebin i provided)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since its a set of functions why not put it as a helper?

`$this->load->helper('myclass');`

`$this->myclass->fetchlinks();`

Comment: As simple as it is, I didn't think of this. Thanks for the suggestion, I'll try this!